# How best to organize my Project for optimal nginx usage

Tags: java, php, jsp, tomcat, nginx

I have been developing web projects for quite a while now. Some of them hosted on Tomcat/JBOSS (Java webapps), some on Apache (PHP applications).

I wish to horizontally scale my applications and came across nginx and right now I am using nginx as a reverse proxy for my tomcat and apache servers (on different machines within the LAN)

Until now, I have been rendering web-pages using jsp/php templates, i.e., inserting menu-bars, headers, footers via these templates. These template(s) are dynamic, i.e., They have to be inserted depending on the Access level of the user.

The user can be Administrator or Just an employee with differing access rights, which are managed by the application itself. The pages that are not accessible to a particular user should not be accessible by him (Even by directly entering the URL). Right now, we handle this by server-side redirection.

Now, the problem is, I wish to reduce the load on my apache/tomcat servers without compromising on such security aspects as mentioned above.
And I was wondering whether there was a way to completely separate out my jsp/php code from the static content by re-organizing my Project, but while doing this the following points have to be kept in mind,

- I wish to manage file level access via my application, i.e., A user should not be able to access any of the static project files by directly accessing it via the URL.
- I wish to use nginx as a Load balancer and for its advantage of quickly delivering static content.

Answer (score 1):

Well it would need a big change on how to work but you could use server side includes.

Information about `SSI`

- [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)
- [nginx ssi module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSsiModule)
- [varnish esi](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ESIfeatures) (varnish esi are `SSIZ)

I added varnish because it has a tons of features and it sole purposes is caching. And what I learned is you should use a tool where it is made for, not try to force a tool to use it like it isn't ment to be.
Also I added varnish because we had issues using the ssi of nginx with Zend Framework 2, while varnish had not.

Now you think some nice info, but what is `SSI`.

Like I said SSI stands for server side includes. Which roughly translates to, you split your html to multiple HTML files, which can be cached separately.

You can have for instance the following HTML (not trying to win the beauty contest, so it is ment as an example).

```
<div>Current username</div> /* block a */
<div>General menu</div> /* block b */
```

What you do with `SSI` is separated the html into blocks (just like HTML :P ).

Block a, is the current timestamp (`<?= time(); ?>`) we don't want to cache that so we say that to the SSI, don't cache block a, or for 1 second.

Block b, is a general menu (no ACL, so the same for everyone). The first time the bock is included the `SSI` makes a request to get the `HTML` for the block. We say to the `SSI` handler (nginx/varnish/etc) you may save this part for 1 day.

Now the SSI handler has all the HTML blocks, fixes them and sends them to the user. Et voila, plain html noting to worry about.

But then the second request hits (same day).

Now only block a has to be retrieved because block b is still cached. So only a small part of the page has to request to the server.

Hope this intro explains the basics of `SSI`.

tldr;

Use `SSI`, it could lead to less traffic to the web servers, and will cache a lot of static content.